# The origin server did not find a current representation for the target or is not willing to disclose that one exists

Tags: spring-mvc, tomcat, intellij-idea

I was trying to learn Spring MVC and got a problem running my very first project in Intellij IDEA and I spent the whole day trying to find the solution over the internet and I was not able to find it.

I set up intellij and configured tomcat server but this [error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kODxB.png) "The origin server did not find a current representation for the target or is not willing to disclose that one exists." happened.
[here is how my configuration settings look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NNICU.png)

Here is the link to my project
https://drive.google.com/open?id=1S514QgU9XYV9EGzY1vmknnl-ywMulZvp

Can anyone help me figure out what configuration problem I might have.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like wrong artifact type is used in your project. Please try to set both Spring libraries to the same version (e.g 4.3.18), check that they are added to war-exploded artifact and select it in your Tomcat configuration. Remove "out" folder and run your configuration. It should start fine.

Comment: Thank you for your comment! I wanted to use Spring 5.0.8. I have all the library files downloaded but Intellij by default downloads additional lib files. I don't know why.